# Is a P-series Limited To a Coefficient Over A Variable with Exponent

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Is a P-series limited to the function of type: $\frac{Coefficient}{n^2}$ ? Could the P-series be used to determine the convergence of divergence or a function like: $\frac{ln(n)}{n^3}$ ? If not Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Could be used" ... that is right!

Although $\sum \frac{\ln n}{n^2}$ is not, itself, a $p$ series, still $p$ series **could be used** to prove its convergence.

For example, compare  $\sum \frac{\ln n}{n^2}$ to the $p$ series $\sum \frac{1}{n^{3/2}}$ to show that $\sum \frac{\ln n}{n^2}$ converges.